# Magento: duplicate payment module X times with own admin config

Tags: magento, module, payment, checkout

I am trying to think of a way to reduce my code base for 2 similar payment modules I am developing. The two models share some logic, which could be abstracted with the use of admin config options.

For example, both modules are used to calculate instalments. Module 1 specification dictates that maximum number of instalments is 6 with 4% interest rate, but Module 2 specification allows for up to 12 instalments with 6% interest. It would be of additional benefit if I could dynamically add N instances of the module.

Now, my development environment consists of multiple repositories (each module has its own repository) and everything is connected with composer. I would like this module to live in one directory and an easy way to "duplicate" (by that I mean: display new payment options in the checkout, with its own setting) the module.

I hope the question is clear enough. If not, please tell me what information would you need to understand it better.

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: I haven't done any actual code yet. I am trying to figure out the process first. I've asked the question with the intention to see different approaches others might have. I was thinking about making abstract class but that means I need to extend it and make new module each time - which is what I would like to avoid. I would appreciate any links or material where I could read more about the problem.